# How obtain directly the model from a query? -> CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I obtain the model directly from a query in Code Igniter?

Model

```
<?php
class User_Model extends CI_Model {

    public $user_id;
    public $name;
    public $team_id

    public function getTeamName() {
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('team');
        $this->db->where('team_id',$this->team_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $team = $query->row();
        if($empresa == null){
            return "";
        } else {
            return $team->name;
        }
    }

public function getUser($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $id));
    $user = $query->row();
    return $user;
}
```

I would like getUser($id) function returns a user object like 'new User_Model()' to be able to use **getTeamName()** function in the view. Can I do it? 
Now returns an object, but not a User_Model() object.

Comment: the question is against the OOPS concept

Comment: the correct approach: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Answer (score 0):

is wrong call a method in the model from the view.

in the model use

```
function getUser($id){

    $query = $this-db->select('*')
            ->from('users')
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->get();

        return $query->result();

}
```

this return a object with all data, then you call the method in the controller like this

```
$data['user_model'] = $this->model_name->getUser($id);
$this->load->view('Your_View',$data);
```

then in the view  $user_model is the object

in the view

```
print_r($user_model);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the model is loaded, in your view you can access any public function or property like:

`$this->user_model->getUser()` or `$this->user_model->team_id`

View:

```
<?php

echo $this->user_model->getUser(1)->username;
```

This is against MVC in some respects but I can understand the logic behind doing so based on the following scenario where you want to say use `num_rows` and `result` without doing count:

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function getUsers() {
        return $this->db->get('users');
    }
}

class Some_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['users'] = $this->user_model->getUsers();
        $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php

if ($users->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($users->result() as $row) {
        echo $row->username;
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another possibility you can use

create a `Team_model` and an `User_model`

The `Team_model` could look like

```
class Team_model extends CI_Model
{

    $arrTeamNames = [];

    public function getTeamName($team_id) 
    {
        if (!isset($this->arrTeamNames[$team_id]))
        {
            $query = $this->db
                ->select('name')
                ->from('team')
                ->where('team_id',$this->team_id)
                ->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() ==  1)
            {
                $objTeam = $query->row();
                $this->arrTeamNames[$team_id] = $objTeam->name;
                return $objTeam->name;
            }
            return '';
        }
        return $this->arrTeamNames[$team_id];
    }
}
```

and the `User_model`

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function getUser($id) 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $id));
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            $user = $query->row(0, 'User_Object');
            return $user;
        }
    }
}

class User_Object
{
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        $ci = get_instance();
        $ci->load->model('Team_model');
        return $ci->team_model->getTeamName($this->team_id);
    }
}
```

> Note in the `User_model` you have an additional `User_Object` which
>   gets mapped by the `row()` function which is well documented
>   [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows).

Now if you call this model in one of your controller and pass it to your view you actually can access to a model function in a proper way e.g.

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function detail($user_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $objUser = $this->User_model->getUser($user_id);
        $this->load->view('user-detail', ['objUser' => $objUser]);
    }
}
```

//user-detail view

```
echo $objUser->getTeamName();
```